# cannot run python 3.6 on atom(Already tried:downloaded script and added path in environment variables)

Tags: python-3.x, atom-editor

[image]

I installed Python 3.6 on my computer(windows 10) and it works(plz refer to the right on the screenshot. But it cannot work on Atom.(plz refer left on the screenshot).

I have downloaded script packages and added python path in environment variables settings;However, it still does not work.The error message shown below is garbled(labelled as red in the screenshot) so there is no clue for me to presume what might happen. Can somebody suggest me how else can I try to solve the problem? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to run a script in atom, using the script module, make sure the first line of your script is `#!path_to_python_interpreter`.
When I do this the script will run using whichever version of python I enter on line 1.

I have two virtual environments on my Mac to run either python 2.7.13 or python 3.6. If I activate the 3.6 environment, and then run Atom from the command line, Atom will use whichever version of python that was activated.